# Blender denoise node producing black image

Tags: compositing-nodes, denoise

To be clear, the denoise node has been working wonders for me, but sometime over the last week or so it has stopped working in all of my project files (including ones that worked).

I have a single denoise node connected between the render layer and the composite and viewer outputs. The image is shown if I remove the denoise node. No errors are produced in the console during the rendering or compositing.

I wonder if this could be a file permission issue. I'm running linux, and when I started using Luxcore Rendere, it's denoiser couldn't run because the denoise program wasn't marked as executable. Doing so fixed the issue with luxcore.

[image: compositor with denoise node]
[image: compositor without denoise node]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm experiencing similar issues on Blender 2.83 on Arch. I believe it to be related to [a bug](https://github.com/OpenImageDenoise/oidn/issues/76) in OpenImageDenoise (oidn) or in the way Blender is trying to link it. I was able to fix the issue on my system by **downgrading to openimagedenoise 1.1.0-1**.

I'm currently investigating as to whether this issue is documented in the appropriate project, and will update this answer once I have a bug number for it.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem when I wanted to render only a certain part of the render. After disabling the render area and just render the whole thing, it worked again.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and how to do it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)